# How to print a line if it contains a string from another file?

Tags: python, list, file, find

Python how to print line if line is containing a string from another file?

A text file:

```
test.com
test2.com
test3.com
```

Another text file:

```
test.com:user:pass
test3.com:user:pass
test9.com:user:pass
```

(I'm getting two list from two files)

```python
a = ['test1.com,user,pass','test2.com,user,passw','tes4.com,user,pass']
b = ['test5.com','test1.com','test2.com']

temp = a[:]
for i in range(len(a)):
    temp[i] = temp[i].split(':')[0]
for i in b:
    if i in temp:
        print i
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What should the output be?

Comment: I'm not english, output sould be print item from list if containing string from another list

Comment: any helps? please

Comment: Not English, but data is universal.  Show the exact output you expect from the input given.

Comment: I mean my english is bad.....

Comment: Output should be printed of item from list if containing string from another list

Comment: That is fine, no issues. Could you add what you think the right result is in your question? Edit the question

Comment: :)) :) So, I need to print a line if line is containing a string from another file.

Comment: Question is edited I am waıtıng your helps

Comment: **Show** the output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = ['test1.com,user,pass','test2.com,user,passw','tes4.com,user,pass']
b = ['test5.com','test1.com','test2.com']
temp = a[:]
for i in range(len(a)):
    temp[i] = temp[i].split(',')[0]
for i in range(len(temp)):
    if temp[i] in b:
        print a[i]
```

This will print the content of the other list as needed.
test1.com,user,pass
test2.com,user,passw

Comment: Did you replace a and b with the actual list names? If, yes, could you add your source code in the question?

Comment: And do check that the second last line has this 'if i in temp:' because I had updated that later

Comment: And I need to print site.com:user:pass not site.com (so ı need to print other  list) I'm sorry to bother you

Comment: No problem. Try to be clearer while asking the next time. We are here to help only if we can understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
a = ['test1.com,user,pass','test2.com,user,passw','tes4.com,user,pass']
b = ['test5.com','test1.com','test2.com']
a =  [i.split(',') for i in a]
final_list = [''.join(i) for i in a if i[0] in b]

print final_list
```

now gives you the site, username, and password if the site exists in list b